# Python matplotlib blocking programm on server

Tags: python, matplotlib, server

While creating a plot with matplotlib python gets stuck at following line:
`plt.axhline(y=y, color=c, linestyle='-')`

The programm runs fine on my local machine, but on the server its not working. There are no exceptions raised (try/except catches nothing).
I only get a Loop thread traceback in the logs:

```
File "/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2401, in axhline
    return gca().axhline(y=y, xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, **kwargs)
  File "/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 773, in axhline
    self.add_line(l)
  File "/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2304, in add_line
    self._update_line_limits(line)
  File "/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2333, in _update_line_limits
    if line_trf == self.transData:
  File "/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 2165, in __eq__
    elif self._x == self._y:
  File "/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 1774, in __eq__
    return np.all(self.get_matrix() == other.get_matrix())
  File "/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 1570, in get_matrix
    return self.get_affine().get_matrix()
  File "/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 2441, in get_affine
    return Affine2D(np.dot(self._b.get_affine().get_matrix(),
  File "/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 2441, in get_affine
    return Affine2D(np.dot(self._b.get_affine().get_matrix(),
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in dot
```

I changed the backend of matplotlib from `agg`(default) to `TkAgg`, but its still the same.
I also checked the input to the method `axhline`. In both cases (local and server) the input is the same (y=1250 and c='y').
If i remove the line of code the next method it is stuck is `plt.savefig(path)`.

Here are some more details:

- python version: 3.8.8 (python3 --version)
- matplotlib version: 3.7.1 (python3 -m pip list)
- Other methods like `plt.plot(x,y)`, `plt.xlabel('x')`, `plt.ylabel('y')`, `plt.text(x,y,'lbl')` and `plt.title('title')` seem to work fine (or at least do not block the code).
- With `matplotlib.rcsetup.all_backends` i get following response:
  `['GTK3Agg', 'GTK3Cairo', 'GTK4Agg', 'GTK4Cairo', 'MacOSX', 'nbAgg', 'QtAgg', 'QtCairo', 'Qt5Agg', 'Qt5Cairo', 'TkAgg', 'TkCairo', 'WebAgg', 'WX', 'WXAgg', 'WXCairo', 'agg', 'cairo', 'pdf', 'pgf', 'ps', 'svg', 'template']`